# Is there an efficient way to "process/enrich" each element of a matrix/data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to *process* or *enrich* each element of a matrix/data frame?

It is more like merging data from 3 different sources:

```
# init
library(glue)
set.seed(2304195)
metadata <- data.frame(p.status = sample(c('High', 'Low'), 200, TRUE),
                       type = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), 200, TRUE))
rownames(metadata) <- paste0('sample-', 1:200)

values <- matrix(runif(100, 0, 5))
for(i in 1:99) {
  values <- cbind(values, runif(100, 0, 50))
}
colnames(values) <- paste0('sample-', sample(1:200, 100))
rownames(values) <- paste0('gene-', 1:100)

scores <- t(scale(t(log2(values + 1))))
```

Now, I want to somehow merge the data from the 3 sources `values`, `scores`, and `metadata`. Please note, that not all rows of `metadata` are used for this merge, as different iterations require different subsets of `metadata`.

Right now, I use a nested **for** loop:

```
# 'enriching' data
for(j in seq_along(rownames(values))) {
  for(k in seq_along(colnames(values))) {
    values[j, k] <- glue('ID: <b>{colnames(values)[k]}</b>\n',
                         'p. status: <b>{metadata$p.status[which(rownames(metadata) == colnames(values)[k])]}</b>\n',
                         'type: <b>{metadata$type[which(rownames(metadata) == colnames(values)[k])]}</b>\n',
                         'symbol: <b>{rownames(values)[j]}</b>\n',
                         'log<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>{round(as.numeric(values[j, k]), 2)}</b>\n',
                         'z-score: <b>{round(scores[j, k], 2)}</b>')
  }
}
```

While for a 100 × 100 matrix the time consumption is *acceptable*, it is not for an *e.g.* 300 × 2500 matrix.

I am sure (at least I hope), that there is a more efficient way to merge the data.

Maybe a nested **foreach** loop and `%dopar%`?

Would it make sense, to subset `metadata` beforehand to avoid the comparisons within the `[]` brackets? Are these CPU-consuming?

Answer (score 1):

While `for` loops can be efficient if done well, you are missing a great opportunity to improve speed by relying on R's vectorization of things. For instance, I'll replicate your process and remove one of the loops.

```r
values2 <- values # to keep `values` the original numbers
for(j in seq_along(rownames(values2))) {
  for(k in seq_along(colnames(values2))) {
    values2[j, k] <- glue('ID: <b>{colnames(values2)[k]}</b>\n',
                          'p. status: <b>{metadata$p.status[which(rownames(metadata) == colnames(values2)[k])]}</b>\n',
                          'type: <b>{metadata$type[which(rownames(metadata) == colnames(values2)[k])]}</b>\n',
                          'symbol: <b>{rownames(values2)[j]}</b>\n',
                          'log<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>{round(as.numeric(values2[j, k]), 2)}</b>\n',
                          'z-score: <b>{round(scores[j, k], 2)}</b>')
  }
}
values2[1:3, 1, drop = FALSE]
#        sample-190                                                                                                                                           
# gene-1 "ID: <b>sample-190</b>\np. status: <b>Low</b>\ntype: <b>A</b>\nsymbol: <b>gene-1</b>\nlog<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>4.34</b>\nz-score: <b>-1.6</b>" 
# gene-2 "ID: <b>sample-190</b>\np. status: <b>Low</b>\ntype: <b>A</b>\nsymbol: <b>gene-2</b>\nlog<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>4.55</b>\nz-score: <b>-1.43</b>"
# gene-3 "ID: <b>sample-190</b>\np. status: <b>Low</b>\ntype: <b>A</b>\nsymbol: <b>gene-3</b>\nlog<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>1.59</b>\nz-score: <b>-2.4</b>"
```

Now if we remove the inner loop, notice all references to the `[,k]` indexing goes away, and we're dealing with whole vectors at a time.

```r
values3 <- values
for(j in seq_along(rownames(values3))) {
  values3[j,] <- glue('ID: <b>{colnames(values3)}</b>\n',
                      'p. status: <b>{metadata$p.status[match(colnames(values3), rownames(metadata))]}</b>\n',
                      'type: <b>{metadata$type[match(colnames(values3), rownames(metadata))]}</b>\n',
                      'symbol: <b>{rownames(values3)[j]}</b>\n',
                      'log<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>{round(as.numeric(values3[j,]), 2)}</b>\n',
                      'z-score: <b>{round(scores[j,], 2)}</b>')
}
identical(values2, values3)
# [1] TRUE
```

But we can get rid of the `for` loop altogether with more understand of how `matrix` objects are formed. First, a helper function:

```r
mtx <- function(z, byrow = FALSE) matrix(rep(z, length(z)), nrow = length(z), byrow = byrow)
```

Note that if we look at *just* the `ID:` component of your results, then

```r
gsub("\n.*", "", values2[1:3, 1:3])
#        sample-190              sample-97              sample-130             
# gene-1 "ID: <b>sample-190</b>" "ID: <b>sample-97</b>" "ID: <b>sample-130</b>"
# gene-2 "ID: <b>sample-190</b>" "ID: <b>sample-97</b>" "ID: <b>sample-130</b>"
# gene-3 "ID: <b>sample-190</b>" "ID: <b>sample-97</b>" "ID: <b>sample-130</b>"
```

see that the values are identical within a column and vary column-to-column. We can replicate this matrix with a single call:

```r
mtx(colnames(values)[1:3], byrow=TRUE)
#      [,1]         [,2]        [,3]        
# [1,] "sample-190" "sample-97" "sample-130"
# [2,] "sample-190" "sample-97" "sample-130"
# [3,] "sample-190" "sample-97" "sample-130"
```

Repeating this process for the other values, and transposing it (`byrow=FALSE`) for `symbol` (since they repeat along rows instead of columns), we get this:

```r
values4 <- values # in order to get the right shaped matrix, no other reason
values4[] <- glue('ID: <b>{mtx(colnames(values), byrow=TRUE)}</b>\n',
     'p. status: <b>{mtx(metadata$p.status[match(colnames(values), rownames(metadata))], byrow=TRUE)}</b>\n',
     'type: <b>{mtx(metadata$type[match(colnames(values), rownames(metadata))], byrow=TRUE)}</b>\n',
     'symbol: <b>{mtx(rownames(values), byrow=FALSE)}</b>\n',
     'log<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>{round(as.numeric(values), 2)}</b>\n',
     'z-score: <b>{round(scores, 2)}</b>')

identical(values2, values4)
# [1] TRUE
values4[1:3, 1, drop = FALSE]
#        sample-190                                                                                                                                           
# gene-1 "ID: <b>sample-190</b>\np. status: <b>Low</b>\ntype: <b>A</b>\nsymbol: <b>gene-1</b>\nlog<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>4.34</b>\nz-score: <b>-1.6</b>" 
# gene-2 "ID: <b>sample-190</b>\np. status: <b>Low</b>\ntype: <b>A</b>\nsymbol: <b>gene-2</b>\nlog<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>4.55</b>\nz-score: <b>-1.43</b>"
# gene-3 "ID: <b>sample-190</b>\np. status: <b>Low</b>\ntype: <b>A</b>\nsymbol: <b>gene-3</b>\nlog<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>1.59</b>\nz-score: <b>-2.4</b>"
```

This is significantly faster. I'll show all three variants:

```r
res <- bench::mark(
  loops2 = {
    values2 <- values
    for(j in seq_along(rownames(values2))) {
      for(k in seq_along(colnames(values2))) {
        values2[j, k] <- glue('ID: <b>{colnames(values2)[k]}</b>\n',
                              'p. status: <b>{metadata$p.status[which(rownames(metadata) == colnames(values2)[k])]}</b>\n',
                              'type: <b>{metadata$type[which(rownames(metadata) == colnames(values2)[k])]}</b>\n',
                              'symbol: <b>{rownames(values2)[j]}</b>\n',
                              'log<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>{round(as.numeric(values2[j, k]), 2)}</b>\n',
                              'z-score: <b>{round(scores[j, k], 2)}</b>')
      }
    }
    values2
  },
  loops1 = {
    values3 <- values
    for(j in seq_along(rownames(values3))) {
      values3[j,] <- glue('ID: <b>{colnames(values3)}</b>\n',
                          'p. status: <b>{metadata$p.status[match(colnames(values3), rownames(metadata))]}</b>\n',
                          'type: <b>{metadata$type[match(colnames(values3), rownames(metadata))]}</b>\n',
                          'symbol: <b>{rownames(values3)[j]}</b>\n',
                          'log<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>{round(as.numeric(values3[j,]), 2)}</b>\n',
                          'z-score: <b>{round(scores[j,], 2)}</b>')
    }
    values3
  },
  noloop = {
    values4 <- values # in order to get the right shaped matrix, no other reason
    values4[] <- glue('ID: <b>{mtx(colnames(values), byrow=TRUE)}</b>\n',
                      'p. status: <b>{mtx(metadata$p.status[match(colnames(values), rownames(metadata))], byrow=TRUE)}</b>\n',
                      'type: <b>{mtx(metadata$type[match(colnames(values), rownames(metadata))], byrow=TRUE)}</b>\n',
                      'symbol: <b>{mtx(rownames(values), byrow=FALSE)}</b>\n',
                      'log<sub>2</sub> expression: <b>{round(as.numeric(values), 2)}</b>\n',
                      'z-score: <b>{round(scores, 2)}</b>')
    values4
  },
  min_iterations = 10
)
```

```r
res
# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result            memory                  time            gc               
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>            <list>                  <list>          <list>           
# 1 loops2         3.7s     3.8s     0.259   32.61MB   0.0649     8     2     30.83s <chr [100 x 100]> <Rprofmem [40,078 x 3]> <bench_tm [10]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
# 2 loops1       73.9ms  120.6ms     8.90     3.23MB   0         10     0      1.12s <chr [100 x 100]> <Rprofmem [4,151 x 3]>  <bench_tm [10]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
# 3 noloop       66.9ms   67.7ms    14.8      2.49MB   0         10     0   677.63ms <chr [100 x 100]> <Rprofmem [51 x 3]>     <bench_tm [10]> <tibble [10 x 3]>
```

Two takeaways from this:

- Because the default of `bench::mark` is `check=TRUE`, this confirms that all returned values are of equal value.
- Looking at `` `itr/sec` `` (iterations per second) of the benchmark results, `loops1` is 34x faster than `loops2`, and `noloop` is 1.66x faster than `loops1` and 57x faster than `loops2`.

(Note that the times `min` and `median` are using different units, `s` seconds for `loops2`, and milliseconds for `loops1` and `noloop`.)

Comment: Dear r2evans,

your answer provides a massive performance boost to me. Thank you very much!
Though, your solution works perfect for squared matrices, it does not for non-squared ones.
Therefore, I tried to adapt your solution for any-shaped matrices with
`mtx <- function(z, nrow = length(z), ncol = length(z), byrow = FALSE) matrix(rep(z, length(z)), nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol, byrow = byrow)`
This works *somehow* as it throws a warning: data length differs from size of matrix.
But the result looks correct.
Is there any idea to improve my edit to prevent this warning?